# How to check if programm installed with cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, chocolatey

```
@echo off 
color 06
title created by AAIE
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
choco install youtube-dl
set /p input="Enter Link For Playlist:" 
set /p index="Enter Index For videos Seprated by ',':"
mkdir playlist_videos
cd playlist_videos
youtube-dl --playlist-items %index% %input%
```

how can I check if choco or youtube_dl is installed in windows or not or the main question what is the conditions i need to check if it true then use commands directly if not installed then it will install them
and use the same commands

Comment: if for instance `choco` is in the path, you can do `where choco`. If it is not in path, then you'll need to recursively search for it which can take a little longer `where /R %systemroot% choco.exe`

Comment: i don't want to ask i user i want to check automaticly when run batch file if choco and youtube-dl is install if not install them so how can i dont that @KJ

Comment: @Gerhard but how can i check if this file exist what should type in batch file i know the command now but how should i check if it return true or false in batch file

Comment: @KJ i know what you mean but i need it work fast not ask user about anything just work

Comment: here's an example using conditional operators. `(where choco)>nul 2>&1 && echo Choco installed || echo Choco not installed`

Comment: @Gerhard i don't understand >nul 2>&1 what is that??

Comment: redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` stream and then redirecting `stdin` to `nul` so it does not display unwanted information during the find process.

Comment: @Gerhard where can i read about that can you give me a refernce to get full information about 2>&1 meaning of this

Comment: I've added a little more on that in my answer below, but [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stdin+stdout+and+stderr) are plenty of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples using `where` to locate and perform actions based on the result:

```
@echo off
(where choco.exe)>nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Choco not installed. Installing now..
    @"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
)

choco install youtube-dl
set /p input="Enter Link For Playlist:" 
set /p index="Enter Index For videos Seprated by ',':"
mkdir playlist_videos
cd playlist_videos
youtube-dl --playlist-items %index% %input%
```

or by using conditional operators:

```
@echo off
(where choco.exe)>nul 2>&1 && goto :installed || goto :install
:install
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

:installed
choco install youtube-dl
set /p input="Enter Link For Playlist:" 
set /p index="Enter Index For videos Seprated by ',':"
mkdir playlist_videos
cd playlist_videos
youtube-dl --playlist-items %index% %input%
```

Note these are straight forward examples, there are no error handling built in, like what happens if coco install fails, etc.

As per your question on `2>&1 >nul`

`stdout` (seen as `1>` when redirecting) is the output stream of a command where `stderr` (seen as `2>` when redirecting.)

When doing `>nul` or `> file.txt` we are effectively redirecting the output of a command to `nul` (not seen on console) or to a file (logging purpose) but not everything goes to the `stdout` stream by default. so we need to redirect stderr stream to stdout, then redirect `stdout` to `nul` or a file.

You can obviously also redirect independently.

```
commandname 1>out.log 2>error.log
```

Comment: but what &1 and 2 represent in this code ?? @Gerhard

Comment: exactly what I said. We are redirecting the output of the `where` command to `nul` so that it is not displayed in the console. We don't want to see that, we simply want to know if it is installed or not.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help now i understand sorry for wasting your time @Gerhard